# How to expose product data to Policy List on SPCRM

Tags: kademi

On SPCRM I'm trying to expose Product Name on the Policy List page, inside the column called: Insurance Type.

Using inspect and console tool I could not locate the missing data

I am logged in as this user:
https://spinsurance.admin.kademi.com.au/manageUsers/116783806/#summary-tab

Policy List page:
https://crm.spinsurance.co.nz/leads/?query=&leadType=active&from=0&size=100

The product data is only exposed once you click a policy (under Insurance Type section):
example: https://crm.spinsurance.co.nz/leads/148615383/

I would like to know where / how I can update the lead/policy query to also include product data (Insurance Type) within the Policy list page.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so assuming you have a custom field on your journey to hold the insurance type, similar to this example which has a field called "claim_recordId"
[image: Example custom field configuration]

Then the JSON response on the leads page will include that in the fields object, eg:

[image: Example JSON response showing the custom field]

You can then customise the JS for the leads page to show that field in a column

Comment: Thanks Brad.

I don't think that's quite it. I looked via console.logs and the data I'm after is not found under the fields object, aka Journeys 'extra fields' section.

To give an example, on the Lead Profile page the data found under $page.lead.leadProducts and *not* from the 'getLeadExtraFieldsMap()' data set.

I need to find the equivalent data on the Policy List page https://crm.spinsurance.co.nz/leads/?query=&leadType=active&from=0&size=10
By either appending to the elastic search string or another way.

Comment: Custom fields are definitely included in the fields object, as shown above. If you're not seeing it there then try reindexing.

Comment: Hi Brad, It's still not showing correctly even after a reindex. There is no reference to insuranceCompany and insuranceType in the fields object. I can see it's mapped in the index: https://spinsurance.admin.kademi.com.au/manageSearch/lead/. And I can see the Extra Fields in the Journey: https://spinsurance.admin.kademi.com.au/funnels/policy-holder/version1/#properties-tab. However, the data is not present, on any policy list item.

Comment: I've done a few spot checks and all leads seem to have an empty value for insurance company

Comment: I think that information is probably stored as a product related to the lead, and probably doesnt use custom journey fields